# The invalidate function[inside onChildAdded firebase's callback] doesn't invoke onDraw

Tags: java, android, firebase, canvas, callback

Have a good day.

Actually, I have faced an issue, in which, the onDraw function is not being executed when onChildAdded is being invoking inside onChildAdded callback for firebase.

```
        childEventListener = databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {


                        String strikeAsString = (String) snapshot.getValue();

                        invalidate();


                    }
                    }
```

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
```

Comment: What does this `invalidate()` method do?

Comment: Invalidate is used to invoke the callback function "onDraw", which is in order reflect the changes (new drawas) in the canvas.